# Request write permissions on Android

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-external-storage

Sorry, this question has probably been asked multiple times already, but I am struggling with different SDK versions. My app is used as a research instrument and solely installed per .apk directly on tablets, thus no app store. I need to record the answers from users and write them into a text file. And I am having a hard time requesting the permission from users to store the data on the external storage.

I added the following line to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

In the MainActivity, I call askForPermissions in the onCreate function:

```
    public void askForPermissions() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    //TODO no clue, what to do here
                }
            }else{
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission needed to store the data. Please allow storage functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},2);
                }
            }
        }

        createDir();
    }
```

In API version 30, I use the "Intend" and accordingly the settings screen with the permissions shows up and I can grant writing permissions manually - and this works (directory is generated, data stored ...). First questions: In which cases can it happen that there is no external storage manager (hence the TODO)?

What I am struggling with is SDK < 30. This does not seem to work. I do not get permissions and in the app info, I cannot give the app writing permissions manually. The permissions option is disabled. What is the correct way to request permissions in that case (most preferably directly in the app)?

Sorry for the possible double post. Newbie here.

Comment: try this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in manifest

Comment: Oh, thanks. This was an obvious error. I will try it.

Comment: if this works plz upvote !!

Comment: ... and it works! Oh boy! I wasted two days on the issue. In any case: Many, many thanks!

Comment: Then i'm writing it as an answer please accept it so that it can boost my reputation, Thanks  @gbpa005!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work from api 28 up